# How can I express 24 hour time as 12 hour time when using timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: postgresql

How can I express 24 hour time as 12 hour time when using timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL 9.1?

More specifically, I inserted order data into a database and I need to extract it back in its original state.

Original data: `06/10/2013 12:43:30`
Data in DB: `2013-06-10 04:43:30+00`

If I query order data like:
`SELECT order_date AT TIME ZONE('EDT') ...` 
I return `2013-06-10 00:43:30`

I need the `00` in the time to show as `12`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User [**`to_char()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char('2013-06-10 00:43:30'::timestamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')
```

I added `PM` to make the output unambiguous. Consider [available patterns in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE).